# Javascript Object.assign

Tags: javascript, object

I know `Object.assign` can combine two objects in to a new one? What happens if I set the first param is a function with a return object.

```js
const testFactories = {
    object(value) {
        console.log("go to object")
        return { test: value }
    },
    set() {
        return new Set()
    },
}

const testFn = (value) => {
    return test.object(value)
}
const test = Object.assign(testFn, testFactories)
console.log("test", typeof test, test({ a: 1 }))
```

Here I have a `testFn` returns the `test.object`, could someone tell me why after the `testFn` returns, it goes to the `testFactories` object property?

What I thought after I have the value of `testFn`, the origial test will be like

```
const test = Object.assign(test.object({a:1}), testFactories)
```

But how the relashipship between test and testFactories built? I have no idea why it can go to the factories object. Please correct me if any part is wrong.

Comment: Did you read the [Object.assign docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to find out what's supposed to happen, and then run it to see if that happened?

Comment: Moved your code to a snippet so you can press 'Run code snippet' to see whats being logged.

Comment: yes, it will go to testFactories.object and return `{test: {a: 1}}`.

Comment: No, what makes you say that it would do that? Object.assign treats the two arguments you pass it as objects, what makes you think that if you pass it a function, it would run that function?

Comment: I want to know why the return of testFn will find the testFactories.object one?

Comment: What does the function body of `testFn` have to do with object property assignment? `testFn` _never gets run_: functions are a type of object in JS, you can assign properties to them just like any other object, which is what you're telling `Object.assign` to do.

Comment: when I pass the target to be `test.object({a:1}`, what Object.assign add to it? Object.assign will combine two object together, but here the target one is a function, will the source object be added to the result of the target function running?

Comment: Try it and find out: `Object.assign` takes two objects (and if you pass it "not plain objects" such as the function reference `testFn`, it will _forcefully interpret them as objects anyway_) and assigns the object properties of the second argument to the first argument. If you pass it two functions, like in your post, nothing will happen because functions don't (normally) have properties on them. If you change what you pass into `Object.assign`, then _that_ is what's going to get used.

Comment: `test.object( { a: 1 })` **calls the function**, which returns an object, so `Object.assign` will assign properties to that returned object.  A bare `plainFn` is **not** called *(it's a reference to the function)* so it adds properties to that function.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.assign()` doesn't call its arguments as functions, it just treats them as object. It copies the properties of the second argument to the first argument, then returns the first argument.

So your code is effectively equivalent to this:

```js
const testFactories = {
    object(value) {
        console.log("go to object")
        return { test: value }
    },
    set() {
        return new Set()
    },
}

const testFn = (value) => {
    return test.object(value)
}
testFn.object = testFactories.object;
testFn.set = testFactories.set;
const test = testFn;
console.log("test", typeof test, test({ a: 1 }))
```

Since `typeof testFn` is `function`, so is `typeof test` since they're set to the same object.

When you call `test({a: 1})` at the end, it calls `test.object({a: 1})`, which prints the log message and then returns the wrapper object that it creates. That gets logged.